# Use state problem , with style compenents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make hamburger menu. I need the styled components to take the info from the state to toggle the menu and it's not happening.

I want that when I click on the open image the sidebar appears and when I click on the close image it disappear.

My Navigation components

```
import Nav from '../Nav'
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

    
export const Navigation = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    function toggle(){
            setIsOpen(!isOpen)
            console.log(isOpen)
        }

    
    return (
        <>
        <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}/>
        <Nav isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
    </>
    ) 
    }

export default Navigation
```

The sidebar

```
import React from 'react'
import { SideContainer, SideList, SideItem,SideTop,SideLogo,SideClose,SideWrapper } from './SidebarElements'
import Logo from '../../assets/shared/desktop/logo.svg'
import close from '../../assets/shared/mobile/icon-close.svg'
const Sidebar = ({isOpen, toggle}) => {
    
    return (
    <SideWrapper>
    <SideContainer>
        <SideTop>
            <SideLogo src={Logo} alt="logo" />
            <SideClose src={close} isOpen={isOpen} onClick={toggle} alt="close-logo"/>
        </SideTop>
        <SideList>
            <SideItem>HOME </SideItem>
            <SideItem>ABOUT US </SideItem>
            <SideItem>CREATE YOUR PLAN </SideItem>
        </SideList>
    </SideContainer>
    </SideWrapper>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const SideWrapper = styled.div`
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
}
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: ${({ isOpen }) => (isOpen ? "0rem" : "300rem")};
}
```

The nav

```
import React from 'react'
import logo  from '../../assets/shared/desktop/logo.svg'
import opened  from '../../assets/shared/mobile/icon-hamburger.svg'
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"
import './nav.css'
import { Nav,NavContainer,NavMenu ,NavLogo,NavOpen } from './NavElements'
const Navbar = ({toggle}) => {
    console.log(toggle)
return (
    <>
    <Nav>
        <NavContainer>
            <NavLogo  src={logo} alt="logo-coffertoast"/>
            <NavOpen src={opened} onClick={toggle}  alt="logo-open"/>
            <NavMenu>
                <NavLink className="Items" to="/">HOME</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="Items" to="/about">ABOUT US</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="Items" to="/plan" >CREATE YOUR PLAN</NavLink>
            </NavMenu>
        </NavContainer>
    </Nav>
    </>
)
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: The [tour] will show you how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `isOpen` to `SideWrapper` -

```
<SideWrapper>
```

it should be

```
<SideWrapper isOpen={isOpen}>
```